# Previously using System.IO to find and launch shortcut. This has stopped working

Tags: c#, wpf, system.io.directory

**INFORMATION**: I created a WPF application (.net 3.1) for some of our business locations to launch the ERP system we use as well as other tools on a kiosk computer. The ERP system runs through Microsoft Remote Desktop Client and authenticates using an account assigned to the locations. So, the user clicks the ERP button, and the MSRDC sign in window comes up to allow the user to sign in. I am using SYSTEM.IO Directory to find the shortcut added by MSRDC and of course **process.Start()** to start it. I added **Process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true** as this allowed the .lnk to launch. This has worked for around 6 months.

**PROBLEM**: On July 18th I made a background change (literally the app image backdrop) because of a change our company made. When I published and deployed the application, the method to launch our ERP system would run the catch. So, the MSRDCW client comes up and the user then has to click a second button to sign into our ERP system. One of the confuses bits (to me) is that when I test in debugging, the method works as intended. However, after publishing, this problem occurs. I am nowhere near an expert so that may not confuse you all!

Code below:

```
  try
        {
            string upath = @"C:\Users\";
            string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(upath, "kiosk*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
            string[] timsdirs = Directory.GetDirectories($@"{dirs[0]}\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\", "*timsv8*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
            string[] timsfiles = Directory.GetFiles($@"{timsdirs[0]}", "*timsv8*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
            Console.WriteLine("The number of directories within Users is {0}.", dirs.Length);
            Console.WriteLine(timsfiles[0]);
            Process process = new Process();
            process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
            process.StartInfo.FileName = timsfiles[0];
            process.Start();

        }
        //Launches MSRDCW in the event that TIMS .lnk file cannot launch
        catch (Exception)
        {

                Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files\Remote Desktop\msrdcw.exe");
        }
```

If I can provide any other information, or clear anything I will certainly try my best. And I appreciate any information!

Thank you!

Comment: what exception happens, do you at least log it?

Comment: Perhaps you don't have access to one of the folders, after all you are searching in all `kiosk*` user folders (a rather inefficient and brittle method anyway)

Comment: @ASh Yes, the exceptions are logged. The log shows that the specified path is not found. The user name is always simply kioskUser0, so that was changed to kioskUser0. Unfortunately, the result is still the same.

Comment: @Charlieface As you know, you are correct in this method being brittle. I have begun research for a new method of starting the .lnk file. I suppose I was comfortable with this working for too long.

Comment: It looks like there was a change to the devices this app is installed on without me knowing. I changed the target runtime to compliment those devices and this is now working again.

Again, I can see how starting the .lnk this way is brittle, so I will continue to research for more efficient way.

Thanks for your responses!